# Reincarnation story where an immortal warrior falls in love with the Sun God's daughter

Tags: story-identification

I read a story about an immortal-warrior man who served the Sun God and fell in love with the Sun God's daughter. I believe the book was published in the 00's. I also remember the cosmos being mentioned in the book. Also, the main character, the girl, was reincarnated a couple of times and she remembers some bits and pieces of her past lives. She was also treated as some kind of spring goddess, from what I remember.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)