# Fantasy novel that uses Greek mythology

Tags: story-identification, books

It was about 2 Greek couples cursed by a deity and a satanic being. Basically, the man was cursed to be immortal and the girl reincarnates to different animals. It was a Greek myth.

Details I remember:

1. The woman turned into a maggot, eagle, dolphin etc.
2. There was a war and the man killed an enemy who turned out to be the woman who was reincarnated as his enemy.
3. The ending was the curse got broken, the girl went into a tree with a lot of diaries of the man inside.

Comment: Was this a story based on Greek mythology? Or are you looking for a Greek myth?

Comment: What language was the story in? Greek? English?

Comment: I think this question may be a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105279/novel-about-reincarnated-lovers-across-history - can you look at the answers there and see if any of them match? I don't think any of them do, but it's worth a try.

Comment: *Possibly* another duplicate might be https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196568/reincarnation-story-where-an-immortal-warrior-falls-in-love-with-the-sun-gods-d - also, do you remember which year this was published? Roughly when you read it?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not the one, but there are a lot of similarities to Soulmate (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/293979.Soulmate)